# If $x \sim U(Z_n^*)$ then $x^2 \pmod n\sim U(QR_n)$?

Tags: probability, group-theory, number-theory

Define:

$Z_n^*=\{x \in Z_n | \operatorname{gcd}(x,n)=1\}$

$QR_n=\{x \in Z_n | \exists r \in  Z_n \; s.t. \; r^2 =x\}$

How can I show that $x \sim U(Z_n^*) \implies x^2 \pmod n \sim U(QR_n)$?

Thank you.

Comment: please help....

Comment: I guess $x∼ U(Z_n)$ means that $x$ is uniformly distributed over
${\mathbb Z}_n$. I think the implication follows from the fact that every
element of ${\rm QR}_n$ has the same number of square roots in ${\mathbb Z}_n$,
which is equal to the number of elements $y \in {\mathbb Z}_n$ with
$y^2=1$.

Comment: Note that you forgot that I ask about $x \sim U(Z_n^*)$. The same claim about $Z_n$ is not true! for instance $Z_3$: $0^2=0, 1^2=1, 2^2=1$ i.e. 0 has one root and 1 has two roots!

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake, I meant to write $Z_n^*$, not $Z_n$. What I wrote was correct for $Z_n^*$ (which I prefer to write as ${\mathbb Z}_n^*$). The number of solutions of $y^2=1$ in ${\mathbb Z}_n^*$. is $1$ when $n=1$ or $2$; $2$ when $n=4$ or $n=k$ or $n=2k$ with $1<k$ odd; and $4$ otherwise.

Comment: @Derek Holt, do you know how to show this "fact" you mentioned is true? It is equivalent to what I try to show, but I need some explanation why it is true at all.

Comment: Suppose that $a^2=b^2=z$. Let $t=ab^{-1}$. Then $t^2=(ab^{-1})^2=a^2b^{-2}=zz^{-1}=1$. So $a=bt$ where $t^2=1$. Conversely, if $a=bt$ with $t^2=1$, then $a^2=b^2$. So the set of elements whose square is equal to $z$ is $\{at \mid t^2=1\}$, so the the number of such elements is equal to the number of elements $t$ with $t^2=1$.

Comment: @Derek Holt, Thank you! This is an exact and complete answer to my question (in 3 parts). It would be nice to copy it as an answer so I can officially accept it (only if you want).
and again, Thank you.